# how to close a modal dialog in javascript

Tags: javascript, popup, modal-dialog

I use a javascript file provided by others and shows here: http://jsbin.com/fubo/1/edit.
I want to add a button to the opened new window, which acts as the same way as the cancel button in the new confirm dialog.I tried to delete the dom elements of that part, but it doesn't work.How to add a button to the new window contains another html file acts as same as the cancel button in the new confirm dialog?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation of the dialog widget you're using? Have you already checked there to see if it says how to do what you want? If it doesn't, do you really expect us to search through hundreds of lines of code to figure out how to do this undocumented operation?

Comment: There is no doc with the widget, I just want to use in a project,but I am new to javascript.

Comment: If it was provided by others, why don't you ask them?